# TabGui wont Show in Hack Client

Tags: java, minecraft

I tried to an Minecraft Hack Client with an Youtube Tutorial, but The Ingame TabGui wont show up ingame. (The Code for the Tabgui is not finished, but it already should be ingame). In the Video There should be the Gui ingame.

TabGui.java

```
package ClientSettings.Render;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;

import ClientSettings.Modules;
import Events.Event;
import Events.Listeners.EventRenderGui;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.FontRenderer;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.Gui;

public class TabGUI extends Modules{
    
    public TabGUI() {
        super("TabGUI", Keyboard.KEY_NONE, Category.Render);
        toggled = true;
    }

     public void onEvent(Event e) {
           if(e instanceof EventRenderGui) {
               FontRenderer fr = mc.fontRendererObj;
               
               Gui.drawRect(5, 30, 70, 30, 0x90000000);
               
               int count = 0;
              for(Category c : Modules.Category.values()) {
                  fr.drawStringWithShadow(c.name, 10, 40 + count*10, 0x9000000);
              }
    }
}
}
```

HUD.java Code

```
package ClientSettings.HUD;

import java.util.Comparator;


import ClientSettings.Client;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import ClientSettings.Modules;
import Events.Listeners.EventRenderGui;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.FontRenderer;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.Gui;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.ScaledResolution;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.GlStateManager;

public class HUD {
    public Minecraft mc = Minecraft.getMinecraft();
    

    public void draw() {
        ScaledResolution sr = new ScaledResolution(mc);
        FontRenderer fr = mc.fontRendererObj;
        
        GlStateManager.translate(4, 4, 0);
        GlStateManager.scale(2, 2, 1);
        GlStateManager.translate(-4, -4, 0);
        fr.drawString(Client.name, 4, 4, 51-153-255);
        GlStateManager.translate(4, 4, 0);
        GlStateManager.scale(0.5, 0.5, 1);
        GlStateManager.translate(-4, -4, 0);
        fr.drawString(Client.version, 60, 10, 51-153-255);
        
        
        int count = 0;

        for(Modules m : Client.modules) {
            if(!m.toggled) {
                continue;           
                }
            
            Gui.drawRect(sr.getScaledWidth() - fr.getStringWidth(m.name) - 8, + count*(fr.FONT_HEIGHT + 6), sr.getScaledWidth(), 6 + fr.FONT_HEIGHT + count*(fr.FONT_HEIGHT + 6), 0x90000000);
            fr.drawString(m.name, sr.getScaledWidth() - fr.getStringWidth(m.name) - 4, 4 + count*(fr.FONT_HEIGHT + 6), 51-153-255);
            
            count++;
        }
        
        Client.onEvent(new EventRenderGui());
        
    }
}
```

EventRenderGui.java Code

```
package Events.Listeners;

import Events.Event;

public class EventRenderGui extends Event<EventRenderGui>{

}
```

i Did the Same like the Guy in the Video every thing worked, the TabGui was enabled but its just not there
And I'm not familiar with Java, Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Are you sure you called `HUD#draw` somewhere?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Do you mean in minecraft.java class? If you mean that yes.

Comment: Well in that case, do some debugging. Print something in every method and see what gets called and what doesn't.

Comment: I did it, everything Everything works except the TabGui class. I dont know what i did wrong there.

Comment: The onEvent Does not Work

Comment: Well, did you add the event bus code into `Client.onEvent`?

Comment: What do you mean? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What does your `Client.onEvent` method look like

Comment: Do you mean the Event Class? https://pastebin.com/UzHLDNT1

Comment: No, `Client.onEvent`

Comment: I dont understand what you mean sorry

Comment: https://pastebin.com/555mvtg8